# The parameter 'price' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart

Note I Do not want to add required, I am looking for  other solution.

> The parameter 'price' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
> Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.dartmissing_default_value_for_parameter
> {num price}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnoV9.png)

```
class Item {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String desc;
  final String color;
  final String image;
  final num price;

  Item({this.id, this.name, this.desc, this.color, this.image, this.price});
}

final products = [
  Item(
      id: "Codepur001",
      name: "iPhone 12 Pro",
      desc: "Apple iPhone 12th generation",
      price: 999,
      color: "#33505a",
      image: "https://www.pngmart.com/files/15/Apple-iPhone-12-PNG-HD.png")
];
```

Comment: `Item({this.id ="", this.name=""...});` and so on

Comment: but what about price that is number it give error ````A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'num'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'num'```

Comment: His idea is to give a Item a default value for constructor  ``Item({this.id, this.name, this.desc, this.color, this.image, this.price = 0});``

Answer (score 1):

Because the variables in the class are non-null, you should either make them nullable or make them required compulsory from the constructor like so:

##### Making them required

```
class Item {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String desc;
  final String color;
  final String image;
  final num price;

  Item({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.desc,
    required this.color,
    required this.image,
    required this.price,
  });
}
```

##### Making them nullable

```
class Item {
  final String? id;
  final String? name;
  final String? desc;
  final String? color;
  final String? image;
  final num? price;

  Item({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.desc,
    this.color,
    this.image,
    this.price,
  });
}
```

Alternatively, you can assign default values instead of using `required` like so:

```
class Item {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String desc;
  final String color;
  final String image;
  final num price;

  Item({
    this.id = '',
    this.name = '',
    this.desc = '',
    this.color = '',
    this.image = '',
    this.price = 0,
  });
}
```